# DataGrid CellTemplate TabNavigation

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I assume this has been asked before but I couldn't find it, so let me know if it's a duplicate found with other verbiage or something.

The problem is with an SL4 DataGrid which contains multiple CellTemplate's including `Checkbox`, `Button` etc. By default it will only tab through these elements on the first row. If I set `TabNavigation="Cycle"` it will tab through all the elements, but it doesn't move on to the next elements and instead just re-iterates the tabbing through the same DataGrid.

If I set it to `Once` then again it will only tab through the first row....and SL4 doesn't appear to have a `Continue` option to move onto the next object once it reaches the edge.

I'm looking for just an easy way to take the equivalent of `TabNavigation="Cycle"` except when it reaches the last tab-able element in the `DataGrid` then it moves on to the next thing in the tree instead of just tabbing back to the first element in the `DataGrid` again. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is an usability issue of Silverlight, because there's no equivalent of WPF's "Continue" in Silverlight. The option "Cycle" in the DataGrid works as 'expected', because the navigation will be enabled only for your control, moving back to the first element in the DataGrid. There's a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/it-IT/7b391e13-fc98-458c-85ae-47feebff3a41/datagrid-with-tab-navigation?forum=silverlightcontrols) that maybe could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a native way to do this in Silverlight, here is a list of supported key strokes in the data grid control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838112(v=vs.95).aspx

I was able to fake it by using a KeyDown event and checking for Tab then setting the editing cell manually:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Some text" />
    <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyDown="DataGrid_KeyDown">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Some more text" />
</Grid>

    private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
        ObservableCollection<Person> items = dg.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Person>;
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab && dg.SelectedIndex < items.Count -1)
        {
            dg.SelectedIndex++;
            dg.CurrentColumn = dg.Columns[0];
            dg.BeginEdit();
            var cell = dg.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(dg.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya setting the Cell editing isn't the issue since you can specify an editing template for when they double click, or if they just begin in the first template they can tab through the elements of the datagrid fine. The problem persists in where tab is/should be passed off from row to row, left to right, to the last cell where it should then pass tab focus to the next control in the tree. I was hoping I wouldnt have to figure out how to listen for focus in the last cell and then pass it off manually to the next control also. Like I said "Cycle" works fine, but then it doesnt pass it off.

Comment: I'm only setting the Cell editing after I advance the selected item.  I put the key down event on the data grid itself, not the last cell.

Comment: Then how would you pass off focus via tabbing to the next control in the tree past the datagrid?

Comment: I just updated my answer with my entire test.  I don't set TabIndex on the data grid, after my last cell tab the cursor moved into my last text box.  I should have mentioned earlier, I am using SL 5.

Comment: Ah ya I haven't played with it on SL5 yet, just SL4, but maybe I can apply parts of this to my dilemma, will have to look into yet. So far I havent been able to pass it to the next control intuitively yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I had some exp wth SL4 long time back. I will give your problem a try:

See the property you set to get your desired behavior won't work. It will be the Microsoft way only, thus alternative is to write your own code to achieve the required behavior.

My idea is to attach the following event to each datagrid cell:

```
private void DataGridCell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {

   if (keypressed == 'TAB' && last cell of the datagrid)
    {
          e.handled=true;
          int tabIndex = dg.TabIndex;
           tabindex++;
           Control control = GetControl(tabIndex); // You can use visual tree in the method to get it
           control.select();
           control.focus();
   }
 }
```

My apologies I have written pseudo instead of real code, since it will take time for me to recall the code I use to do in SL.

Hope this solution works for you both way, when you tab out of data-grid and reverse tab in to the data-grid.